# как найти индекс элемента в структуре данных ArrayDegue?

Tags: java, list

Как очень быстро найти индекс элемента в `ArrayDegue`? Есть задача где по заданному числу нужно определить его индекс, не проходит один тест, ограничение по времени. Пробовал индексофф, не сработало

Comment: В Java у класса [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) НЕТ метода `indexOf` (в Котлине, похоже, [есть](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-the-indexof-method-of-arraydeque-in-kotlin))

Comment: Раз встаёт такая проблема - может быть, не та структура данных выбрана?

Comment: проитерировать коллекцию и номер итерации и будет индексом

Comment: я изменил структуру на ArrayList, там есть индексофф, все равно превышено по времени

Comment: @esh Вы не привели точное условие задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Если исходная коллекция значений отсортирована, нужно использовать двоичный поиск, сложность составит O(log N).

Для неотсортированной коллекции в общем случае придётся проитерировать по ней хотя бы один раз, то есть сложность поиска будет линейной O(N).

Однако, если будет выполняться многократный поиск по одной и той же коллекции, его можно ускорить, построив карту (мапу) индексов, то есть исходная коллекция `Collection<T>` преобразуется в мапу `Map<T, Integer>`, если все значения уникальны или если нужно запоминать только один (первый) индекс, или же `Map<T,  List<Integer>>` -- чтобы для каждого значения хранить *отсортированный* список всех индексов.  Поскольку "стоимость" поиска по ключу в мапе принимается равной константе O(1), при повторных попытках индекс будет находиться гораздо быстрее.

При этом у типа значений `T` должны быть корректно реализованы методы `equals` и `hashCode`, так как они будут использоваться в качестве ключей.